# Linear transformation: Reflecting a point about a line in $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

I know that the matrix $M_{2\times 2}[\mathbb R]$ for reflecting a point about a line in $\mathbb R^2$ is:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(2\alpha) & \sin(2\alpha)\\
\sin(2\alpha) & -\cos(2\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the matrix $M_{3\times3}[\mathbb R]$ that can perform a reflection on a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ about a line going through $(0, 0, 0)^T$?

Comment: In your title, you’re asking about a reflection, but in the body of the question you want a rotation. Which is it?

Comment: @amd Sorry, my bad, I meant reflection again :P

Comment: One approach is similar to that of computing the reflection in a plane: decompose into components perpendicular to and parallel to the line, reverse the former, and reassemble.

Comment: @amd I think that's the approach I'm looking for, but I don't really see well how it translates to 3D space (I understand the approach in plane). In the plane, you only have 1 angle to worry about, while in space you have 3 essentially...

Comment: Forget about using angles directly and work the direction vector of the line instead. You can do everything with dot products and convert the result to direction cosines or whatever afterwards.

Comment: @amd The vector approach would essentially boil down to doing the reflection on  {(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)} and constructing the new matrix from the column space bases we got?

Comment: That’s one way, but there’s a simpler direct construction. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about angles for a moment and let’s work with a direction vector $\mathbf d$ of the line. You can proceed as you might for computing the reflection in a plane: decompose the vector into components parallel and orthogonal to the line, reverse the orthogonal component and reassemble. That is, $$M\mathbf v = \mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v_\perp = \mathbf v_\parallel-(\mathbf v - \mathbf v_\parallel) = 2\mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v = 2{\mathbf d^T\mathbf v \over \mathbf d^T\mathbf d}\mathbf d-\mathbf v = \left(2{\mathbf d\mathbf d^T \over \mathbf d^T\mathbf d}-I\right)\mathbf v.$$ (I’ve used a well-known formula for orthogonal projection onto a vector here.) The parenthesized expression at the end is the desired reflection matrix.

In terms of direction cosines of the line, we would have $\mathbf d=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^T$, so $\mathbf d^T\mathbf d=1$ and $$M = \begin{bmatrix}2\alpha^2-1 & 2\alpha\beta & 2\alpha\gamma \\ 2\alpha\beta & 2\beta^2-1 & 2\beta\gamma \\ 2\alpha\gamma & 2\beta\gamma & 2\gamma^2-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Another approach might be to note that this reflection is equivalent to a rotation about the line through an angle of $\pi$. Applying [Rodrigues’ rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) yields essentially the above expression.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a tremendous amount :)